# Google Apps Scripts/JDBC/MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am trying to connect Google Apps Scripts to a MySQL server hosted on Rackspace.  I'm using the documentation provided here.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc

I set the parameters correctly in this line of code:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname","user","pw");
```

I receive this error.

```
Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. (line 2)
```

I use Putty to Tunnel to the Database and Port Forward on my local machine and have no issues connecting to other programs that use the Database (Tableau, MySQL etc.).

I am stumped.  Tried multiple user/pw iterations, allowed Google's ports to access the database etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you really specify the ip-address "127.0.0.1" in your code? I think you should specify the ip address of Rackspace server, or domain.

Comment: No, but thank you, I should have clarified.  Turns out the issue was related to HOW I opened access to the database as per Google Documentation. The range of these IP addresses, when entered using CIDR fixed the issue.

    '216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255'
to
    '216.239.32.0/19'

Comment: You should have posted the link of the doucmentation here.

Answer (score 3):

I had many issues with connecting at first, took 3 of us to get it exactly right. In the end I found a webpage, sorry I don't remember which one, that provided me with this:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
   "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=MyUserName;password=*****;");
```

I entered my info, made sure I was using port 1433 and the connection was made. Hope this helps!