# Error when connecting to MSSQL Server with Google Apps Script via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using Google Apps Script. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I am using one of the suggested scripts that's supposed to read data and put it  into a Spreadsheet: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#reading_from_a_database

The error message is:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username, and password

Username and password are OK, the user is DBowner. The port is also correct, I tried to connect to the server via Telnet using:
    o IP-address 1433
and it works.

Here's the code:

```
function foo() {
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP-adress:1433/DBName","user","password");
    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.setMaxRows(100);
    var start = new Date();
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from person");
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
    var row = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
            cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
        }
        row++;
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    var end = new Date();
    Logger.log("time took: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Do you have any idea of what can be wrong? Do I have to make some configuration on my Server? Or in the database? The instructions mentioned above says to ensure that Google's Ip-addresses can reach the database. But instead of listing all of Google's IP-addresses I granted access to all on that port. I also enabled TCP/IP Protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager. And I granted "Remote connections" to the Server in MSSMS. Any other idea, please?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found the answer here:
[Google Apps Scripts/JDBC/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942508/google-apps-scripts-jdbc-mysql)

Obviously, the connection string has to look like this:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP-address:1433;" + "databaseName=DBName;user=username;password=password;");
```

I don't understand why connection string differs from the one in Google Documentation but this one works for me...

Comment: Works great although you do not need to have separate strings for ip and db

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is in the Connection string.

It should be like so

```
          address = '%YOUR SQL HOSTNAME%';
          user = '%YOUR USE%';
          userPwd = '%YOUR PW%';
          dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;databaseName=' + queryDb;
          var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
```

I have an entire tool on GitHub where you are able to connect to MySQL and SQL Servers. I you will be able to use it to help you. I will be constantly updating with more features overtime! You can find it here.

[GOOGLE SPREADSHEET JDBC CONNECTOR TOOL](https://github.com/ebarreat/Google-Spreadsheet-JDBC)