# Can Google App Maker connect to MS SqlServer Database in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, azure-sql-database, google-app-maker

thanks for reading. I have added the App Maker APIs to the Azure firewall as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) I have tried connecting from App Maker to the sqlserver database on azure several ways, and I have triple checked my username and password and used it to connect directly to the database in other applications.

Here are some things I have tried:

```
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433/mydatabase';
var user = 'myusername';
var userPwd = 'mypassword';

function getJDBCConnection() {
  try {
    return Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.message.match(/Failed to establish a database connection/)) {
      throw new Error(err.message + ' Please refer to the ReadMe and edit ' +
                      'your database settings!');
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

and I have also tried creating the connection directly with two methods, first:

```
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433/mydatabase','username', 'password');
```

and also like this

```
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:sqlserver://mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433/mydatabase', {user: 'username', password: 'password'});
```

any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According what I found, when Gooele APP using JDBC connect to Microsoft SQL server, the connection string has some difference.

Here's the example of connection URL :

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;" +  
   "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=MyUserName;password=*****;";
```

Reference:

1. [JDBC: Making a simple connection to a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database)
2. [JDBC: Connection URL sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-ver15#example)

This blog has the same error when connect to Microsoft SQL server, and it solved by change the connection URL: [Error when connecting to MSSQL Server with Google Apps Script via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978380/error-when-connecting-to-mssql-server-with-google-apps-script-via-jdbc/18992272#18992272)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed it myself the same day so I didn't look back at SO until right now : )  the databaseName was the key!  thanks for your help!